# White flash when multiple css background-images are changed through jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I`ve got a page with multiple css background-images. Every time you click a dot (the first three dots are working on the bottom) a new image comes in via jQuery.
Unfortunately, there is a white flash until the browser cached the images.

Is there an workaround to preload the three background-images?

Comment: please share your code for more understanding..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
new Image().src = "url";
```

This will cache your images. If you have a bunch of urls to load:

```
[
    "images/sunset.jpg",
    "images/greece.jpg",
    "images/adventure.jpg"
].forEach(function(url){
    new Image().src = url;
});
```

[image]

As you can see, all three images are preloaded.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('<img/>', {src: your_source}); // for each image
```

Comment: Why use jQuery when you can do it faster in native JavaScript?...

Comment: "Is there an workaround to preload the three background-images with jQuery?" What he ask is what i answer.

Comment: Well... I don't know what to say.

Answer (score 0):

you can pre-load images using js itself.

example :

```
var img1 = new Image();
img1.src = "img1 path";

var img2 = new Image();
img2.src = "img2 path";
```

do this while the page is loading and browser loads all the images and when you need to show them they are already loaded